# Tinymce js file gives 500 error in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, tinymce

I have a recent WP-installation and when I want to edit a page or a post I get a 500 error message in my console.

When I check my error log it tells me the following:

```
[Thu Jul 30 16:01:31 2015] [error] [client some ip address] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '",s(t),"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in path-to-wordpress-installation/wp-includes/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js on line 5, referer: http://www.somedomain.com/subdirectory/wp-admin/post.php?post=7&action=edit
```

Could it be the  problem is with the tinymce file/plugin? How can I solve this?

Kind regards,

Pim

Comment: Should you correct the 'path-to-wordpress-installation' string with the real wordpress path

Comment: well for the question it has of no meaning I guess, the path is just a path... Why should it do you think?

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling WordPress? Core files shouldn't have issues.

Comment: Strange I don't understand any of it... I have it reinstalled and it is still giving me the 500 error when I open the edit page...

Comment: Apperently nobody knows an effective solution for this?